# Is there an Android media payer that allows you to speed up an mp3?

Tags: media-player

Is there a media player for android that can play an mp3 10% faster or slower if the user wants to?

Answer (score 5):

[Rockbox](http://www.rockbox.org/) has a [very early port](http://www.rockbox.org/wiki/AndroidPort) to Android that allows speeding up an MP3 once the [Timestrech](http://download.rockbox.org/daily/manual/rockbox-sansae200v2/rockbox-buildch6.html#x9-1140006.10) option is enabled.  The port is very functional, but the UI and integration with Android still leave much to be desired.  Jon Corbet of LWN did a [good summary article](http://lwn.net/Articles/408626/) a few weeks ago.  The most important [piece of advice](http://forums.rockbox.org/index.php?topic=14177.msg171653#msg171653) before using it:

> Imagine that your screen is a 3x3 grid, where the middle is used as the selector, 
>   left-right-up-down are used as cursor keys. The other directions have special 
>   functions in some screens, e.g. in Now Playing screen with the upper left you can
>   access some playback mode settings.

Having previously enjoyed Rockbox on a several previous Sansa players, I personally excuse the UI shortcomings and use it when playing long stretches of podcasts.  I like that set the playback speed (independant of the pitch) from 50% of the original speed to (at least) 200%.  In increments of a tenth of a percent.  Depending on the subject and the speed with which people speak, I will listen to a podcasts at 175%, 166%, 150%, 133%, or 125%.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [Osplay](http://www.aocate.com/osplay), which does this as its main feature.  I consider it a stable product and am now only issuing bugfixes.

Answer (score 1):

VLC For Android has a feature to play faster or slower
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc&hl=en